# Is every complete metric space closed?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I know that if $A\subset X$ where $X$ is a complede metric space, and $A$ is closed $\iff$ it's complete.

However is every metric space closed? E.g., can I take $X\subset X$ and since $X$ is complete, can I conclude it's closed?

Comment: **Every** topological space is a closed subset of itself.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks, is "topological" just a name for complete metric spaces?

Comment: No. Every metric induces what is called a topology on the underlying set, and the notions of open and closed sets in metric spaces generalize to notions of open and closed sets in topological spaces. If you’ve not encountered topological spaces at all, my comment won’t make much sense, and I’ll substitute a weaker statement: **every** metric space is a closed subset of itself, complete or not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks a lot

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Being closed is relative to some space $Y$ that contains $X$. (By "contains" I mean not just the set containment but also that the metric on $X$ is the restriction of the metric on $Y$.) Technically, we should always say "closed in $Y$" instead of simply "closed", but often the ambient space $Y$ is clear from context so it is not mentioned.

As Brian M. Scott said, every space $X$ is closed in $X$; this is a consequence of the definition of "closed" and has nothing to do with completeness. However, there **is** a connection with completeness:

*A metric space is complete if and only if it is closed in every space containing it.*

Indeed, suppose $X\subset Y$  and $X$ is complete. Take any sequence in $X$ that has a limit in $Y$. Since it converges, it is a Cauchy sequence, hence it has a limit in $X$. This shows $X$ is closed in $Y$.

Conversely, suppose  $X$ is closed in any $Y$ that contains $X$. Let $Y$ be the [*completion*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/604070) of $X$. By construction, $Y$ is complete and $X$ is dense in $Y$. But since $X$ is closed in $Y$, it follows that $X=Y$, hence $X$ is complete.

Comment: Thank you.This is more clear now

Comment: @GRS  if Y is just a norm space, and $X\subset Y$ is banach in Y so X is closed in Y. How to show this, if it is not given that Y is metric space?